# Крашится эмулятор Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Логи:

```
2019-04-01 19:18:07.458 5768-5768/com.example.car E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.car, PID: 5768
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.car/com.example.car.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.car.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
```

Код:

```
 MainActivity:


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button Act_Change, btn;
    private EditText pass;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
            public void AddListenerOnButton () {
                Act_Change = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Act_Change);
                btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
                btn.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                btn.setText("DONE");
                                btn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        MainActivity.this, pass.getText(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        });
        {
            Act_Change.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent("MainActivity2");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В методе onCreate() вы не инициализировали ваши кнопки, отсюда и NullPointerException. Вы их инициализируете не там где надо, в анонимном классе создаете метод по их инициализации и не вызываете его. Вынесите код в метод onCreate:

```
Act_change = findViewById( id вашей кнопки );
btn = findViewById(id кнопки);
```

Либо вынесите этот метод из анонимного класса в ваше Activity:

```
 public void AddListenerOnButton () {
                Act_Change = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Act_Change);
                btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
                btn.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                btn.setText("DONE");

btn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    MainActivity.this, pass.getText(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
```

И в onCreate вызовите его.